# Custom terminal prompt overwrites on itself and generally behaves improperly on OS X Terminal.app

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have the following prompt set in my bash_profile:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;94m\h:\W \u\e[1;93m\$\e[0m \]'
# default = '\h:\W \u\$ '
```

Unfortunately, under certain conditions I encounter problems:

- At a blank prompt, I type a character and then press backspace - the prompt is erased entirely and the cursor goes to the left edge of the terminal instead of simply deleting the character
- If I use the up and down arrow keys for autocompletion for commands that span multiple lines, only the current line changes but the line above (after the prompt) is left alone

How can I correct my prompt to behave properly in all circumstances as the default one does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `\[ ... \]` around the nonprinting parts of the prompts (i.e. the escape sequences), not the entire thing. Since you have them around the entire thing, bash can't figure out how much space on screen the prompt takes up, and will redraw the command in the wrong place. Here's what it should be:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;94m\]\h:\W \u\[\e[1;93m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

Comment: Ahh... makes sense. Thanks so much, this was getting annoying! :)

Comment: Just to clarify Gordons answer, in case you're using colours like in the original question, you need to wrap colour codes with \\[ and \\]. This applies to any codes that do not print on the screen.